# Use response from first axios in second axios call

Tags: vue.js, async-await, axios, request

i wrote an application in VueJS and i have to send first a get call to get the redirect url.

```
this.$axios.get('http://first-url.call').then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.request.res.responseUrl)
      let postUrl = response.request.res.responseUrl
     }).catch(function(error){
      console.log(error)
});
```

In my next call i want to use the "response.request.res.responseUrl" as post url

```
this.$axios.post(postUrl).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
     }).catch(function(error){
      console.log(error)
});
```

Unfortunately, i cannot save the "response.request.res.responseUrl" response in a js variable. I'm not so familiar with async / await so maybe someone can help how i can store the first response into a value that i can use in my second call?

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a solution without async/await**: Make the second axios call within the first successful call. You need to use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for this so you keep the correct `this` on your Vue instance:

```js
this.$axios.get('http://first-url.call').then((response) => {
    console.log(response.request.res.responseUrl)
    let postUrl = response.request.res.responseUrl

    this.$axios.post(postUrl).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log(error)
    });
}).catch((error) =>{
    console.log(error)
});
```

Comment: There's no need for .then in case await is used

Comment: Thanks for the comment @EstusFlask! I removed the async/await version altogether because it was not 100% correct.

Comment: I added the example with await to my post. Good point on arrows, it will obviously be a problem for the OP, considering that `this` is in use

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to deal with this.

The simplest is to create a variable outside the callbacks. **Though the following still relies on your first call completing before the second one.**

```js
let postUrl = null

this.$axios.get('http://first-url.call').then(function(response) {
  postUrl = response.request.res.responseUrl
})
```

The next best (really the best) solution is to use async/await instead of `.then()` so you don't have callback scoping issues. This approach also guarantees you won't have a race condition because it will "await" for the first call to finish before making the second call.

The following would need to take place inside a function with `async`.

```js
async function doWhatever() {
  const response = await this.$axios.get('http://first-url.call')

  const postResponse = await 
  this.$axios.post(response.request.res.responseUrl)
}
```

Finally, the last option is you nest your callbacks. This allows the second callback to have access to the scope of the first callback.

```js
this.$axios.get('http://first-url.call').then(function(response) {
  this.$axios.post(response.request.res.responseUrl).then(function(postResponse)  {
    // do something with the postResponse
  })
})
```

Also, while the above code will work, it's usually better to chain promises.

```js
this.$axios.get('...')
  .then(function(response) {
    // we return the promise so it can be handled in the next .then()
    return this.$axios.post(response.request.res.responseUrl)
  })
  .then(function(postResponse) {
    // do something with the postResponse
  })
```

Notice how this last example starts to look a lot like async/await.

Comment: There is no need for nested promises

Comment: @EstusFlask I'm giving three examples since the OP specifically said they did not understand async/await.

Comment: The last one has problems. Promises are nested and not correctly chained

Comment: @EstusFlask what I've shown will work, but yes, they could be chained. I'll add a followup.

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler to write it exclusively with `async..await` syntax:

```
try {
  let response = await this.$axios.get('http://first-url.call')
  let postUrl = response.request.res.responseUrl;
  response = await this.$axios.post(postUrl)
  ...
} catch (err) {
  ...
}
```

It's beneficial to know the exact meaning of it. The key is correct promise chaining:

```
this.$axios.get('http://first-url.call')
.then((response) => {
  let postUrl = response.request.res.responseUrl;
  return this.$axios.post(postUrl)
})
.then((response) => {...})
.catch(...);
```

This way promises are executed in correct order and don't have unnecessary nested callbacks.

Be aware of incorrect use of `function`, it will lead to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback).